# Socket.io in React Native

Tags: sockets, mobile, websocket, socket.io, react-native

What's the best approach to use socket.io in a react native app? Particularly when it comes to connecting/disconnecting upon entering/exiting/returning to app?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends which parts of your app require the socket connection's data. If it's global, you could connect / disconnect (or dispatch relevant redux actions) in the root component's componentWillMount / componentWillUnmount.

If it's just used in one screen, I'd just use the same lifecycle methods on that screen's main component.

Comment: And then how would child components access it? If the user leaves the apps and comes back would the socket reconnect?

Comment: I'd probably have the root component manage connecting/reconnecting etc, then redux actions to broadcast new data from the socket or to write new data to it. i.e. the other components *don't* access it directly at all